# Memory error due to the huge input file size

Tags: python, file

When I using the following code to read file:

```
lines=file("data.txt").read().split("\n")
```

I have the following error

```
MemoryError
```

the file size is

```
ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 charlie charlie 1258467201 Sep 26 12:57 data.txt
```

Comment: What is the size of the file you are reading?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Obviously the file is too large to be read into memory all at once.

Why not just use:

```
with open("data.txt") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        do_something(line.rstrip("\n"))
```

or, if you're not on Python 2.6 and higher:

```
myfile = open("data.txt")
for line in myfile:
    do_something(line.rstrip("\n"))
```

In both cases, you'll get an iterator that can be treated much like a list of strings.

EDIT: Since your way of reading the entire file into one large string and then splitting it on newlines will remove the newlines in the process, I have added a `.rstrip("\n")` to my examples in order to better simulate the result.

Answer (score 3):

use this code to read file line by line:

```
for line in open('data.txt'):
    # work with line
```