# Load huge data to memory using python

Tags: python

I have to load large data to the memory, and the structure is list.
How can I get another approach.
thanx

Comment: As you see from the answers, we are guessing.  If you could clarify your actual problem a bit more, that would help immeasurably.

Comment: Do you have an example of the data you're loading? What kind of information does it contain? Answers to these questions would make answering your question a bit easier :)

Comment: This is the second question you have asked on the same subject 
in the space of a few minutes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396238/memory-error-due-to-the-huge-input-file-size.

If the answers you got to that question were not adequate then you should have said so in the original question, not ask an even vaguer version of the same question.

Answer (score 2):

process the data line by line, eg

```
for line in open("file"):
    print "do processing of line:",line
```

Or if you really really want to load one whole chunk to memory, you can try memory mapping.

```
import mmap,os,re
bigfile = open( "file2" )
length = os.stat(bigfile.fileno()).st_size
try:
    mapping = mmap.mmap(bigfile.fileno(), length, mmap.MAP_PRIVATE, mmap.PROT_READ )
except AttributeError:
    mapping = mmap.mmap(bigfile.fileno(), 0, None, mmap.ACCESS_READ )
data = mapping.read(length)
# example, finding a pattern
pat =re.compile("pattern",re.M|re.DOTALL)
print pat.findall(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is too large to fit into your computer's memory you will have to read it piece by piece.  If it is not too large you may still want to do this but it might suit your needs to read it into memory in its entirety.  If you edit your question to explain more about your needs and what the characteristics of the data are, then you will get much more helpful answers than this one.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any structure to this data, like a big list of customer records, or is it just one big blob like an image, audio, or video data?  If the former, you might want to restructure the data into a database.  sqlite is included with Python as of Py2.5, and is sufficient for many data sorting and sifting tasks.

And how large is "large"?  You would be surprised how much data Python can keep in memory at once.  Give us some more details about your large list of data.