# Python code gets MemoryError in sl4a

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I got MemoryError when I run the following code in sl4a on my HTC Desire:

```
def load_words():
    print "Loading word list from file..."
    inFile = open(words.txt, 'r', 0)
    wordlist = []
    for line in inFile:
        wordlist.append(line.strip())
    print "  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded.\n"
    return wordlist
```

After it prints "Loading word list from file...", it gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "words.txt", line 92, in <module>
      wordlist = load_words()
    File "words.txt", line 29, in load_words
      for line in inFile:
MemoryError
```

BTW, the file "words.txt" has 83667 English words in it, size 633.6 KB. Help appreciated. 
(The code is part of MIT OpenCourseWare, CS 6.00 -- intro to computer science and programming, problem set 5, ps5_ghost.py)

Is this possibly a bug in sl4a?

**[UPDATE]:**
I tried the following:

```
def load_words():
    print "Loading word list from file..."
    inFile = open(words.txt, 'r', 0)
    wordlist = []
    try:
        for line in inFile:
            wordlist.append(line.strip())
    except MemoryError:
        print 'Oops...'
    print "  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded.\n"
    return wordlist
```

Then, magically, I got

```
Loading word list from file...
Oops...
  83667 words loaded.
```

And the rest of the code worked fine. Does anyone know what caused this?

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided for this question ([Memory error due to the huge input file size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2396238/404469)) may help. The following is adapted from Tim's answer to that question:

```
wordlist = []
with open("words.txt") as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        wordlist.append(line.strip())
```

Also, in terms of debugging, you may want to remove the `wordlist.append(line.strip())` to try to determine whether that line is causing the Memory Error, or (more likely) opening each line in the file.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I actually tried to put `print line` before `wordlist.append(line.strip())` and all 83667 words were printed. Also, my input file is significantly smaller than that 1.2GB monster...

Comment: @lllluuukke Try `inFile.close()` before you try to print the number of words loaded? (Using `with open()` closes the file for you.)

Comment: Tried `with open()`, still got `MemoryError`