# Handling large text files in Python

Tags: python, file-handling

Is there a maximum size for large text files Python 3 can handle?

I have a file `data.json` which has about 3.2 GB. While

```
with open('data.json') as data_file:
    print(data_file)
```

works and gives a proper result:

> ```
> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='data.json' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
> ```

But when it comes to reading the content, e.g. the first line

```
with open('data.json') as data_file:
    print(data_file.readline())
```

it crashes after about a minute with

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "SO.py", line 5, in <module>
>     print(data_file.readline())
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
> ```

Is there a limitation I do not know? How could this problem be solved? Can it be solved at all?

Comment: `for line in data_file: print(line)` Try iterating over the file object instead. You should be able to handle files of any size.

Comment: I'm not really sure about this, but I think you would be getting a MemoryError instead, you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396238/memory-error-due-to-the-huge-input-file-size

Comment: That is exactly why I am wondering, @chngzm , because I would also expect a `MemoryError`. The problem is, that the json file is not human-readable formatted, which means that all information is stored in a single line.

Comment: @chngzm I'm not really sure either, but wouldn't Python 2 precisely fail with a generic `OSError` where Python 3 would be more explicit and raise a `MemoryError`?

Comment: It is a Python 3 issue.