# Memory Error - Python (Huge File Changes)

Tags: python, memory-management

I am trying to change the End of Line(EOL) of a file from Windows to Linux, the file size is 50 GB and writing into the same file, Below is my code :

```
filename = "D:\AddressEvaluation\AddressStandardization\infu\InfutorFile.txt"
fileContents = open(filename,"r").read()
f = open(filename,"w", newline="\n")
f.write(fileContents)
f.close()
```

It gives me this error :

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a87efb13f002> in <module>()
      1 filename = "D:\AddressEvaluation\AddressStandardization\infu\InfutorFile.txt"
----> 2 fileContents = open(filename,"r").read()
      3 f = open(filename,"w", newline="\n")
      4 f.write(fileContents)
      5 f.close()

MemoryError:
```

Am I missing something ?
Please help ?

Comment: You are reading the entire file into virtual memory.  Better to read one line at a time and write each line out (changing the line ending) to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of the size of file. (it might be too large)

Reading a large file into memory all at once throws this error generally.

You can process this by reading the file line-by-line with below code:

```
f1 = open(filename,"w", newline="\n")

with open('D:\AddressEvaluation\AddressStandardization\infu\InfutorFile.txt') as f:
    for fileContents in f:
        f1.write(fileContents)
f1.close()
```

This will solve the problem of `MemoryError`.
You can also look at [Memory error due to the huge input file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396238/memory-error-due-to-the-huge-input-file-size)

Comment: If filename is same as in read write then the output file will be empty.

Comment: @SumitJha thanks to pint that out, I think that is a typo from the questioner in the name of the file writing into.

Comment: I think its not a typo. The are similar solution available on web [newline-conversion-in-python-3](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/newline-conversion-in-python-3/) where they use same filename for conversion. Ofcouse having different file will solve the porblem. But then you have to have double the size available on machine (100G in this case).